# Edit the [feature-store] excerpt

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-excerpt

I saw an empty excerpt for the [feature-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-store) tag and tried to update it. Is this brief description fine and enough?

> Feature store is a data management layer for machine learning with an
> aim to share & discover features and increase efficiency for machine
> learning (it is typically an extended part for MLOps solutions). Use this
> tag for questions about the data management layer for machine learning
> (feature-store concept covers API, persistent layer, UI, etc.) on
> various platforms.

see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/151640)

Comment: The first sentence looks a little "broken English" to me (probably should be "with an aim") and sentences start with a capital letter.

Comment: You're generally free to add excerpts yourself, and with your current reputation, it will be placed in the review queue where experienced reviewers can edit it further, approve or reject it. Any specific reason you're bringing this to meta?

Comment: @ThomA, I made changes based on your suggestion, thx

Comment: @ErikA, I saw here a huge discussion about tags (wrong names if tag has version, burn tags, synonyms, ...) and my idea was check the tag before publishing. If I understand you correctly check on Meta does not make sense, thx.

Comment: I see you've already [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34299264) please wait for it to get reviewed (If that is what your post is about).

Comment: @JIST there's a huge difference to creating a new tag (which can be harmful when it's off topic and requires 1500 reputation) and adding an excerpt to an existing one (nearly never harmful). As long as you're sure the excerpt is accurate and describes the full use of the tag (e.g. there are not a lot of questions using the feature-store tag for something else), you're free to edit it yourself. If you're unsure about something and want to ask meta, it's best to specify what you're unsure about, so we can give feedback on that.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I will wait for approval (I am fine with duration 3 weeks or month or ...), it is not a problem, my idea was check the content (only).

Comment: Hi @ErikA, useful information about different effort for totally new tag vs add only excerpt. It is clear for me, thx

Comment: "*with an aim to share & discover features and increase efficiency for machine learning*" doesn't read very easily, maybe better: "for sharing & discovering features and increasing efficiency for...". // "*it is typically extended part for...*" => "it is typically an extended part for..." // And I'm not sure I really understand what "*extended part*" means anyway in this sentence...

Comment: @chivracq, extended part => it means, a lot of MLOps solutions use feature-store concept as management layer (it is an extension of MLOps).

Comment: The [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34299264) to the excerpt has now been approved.

Answer (score 8):

A lot of that excerpt needs to go into the Wiki.

Why isn't this enough?

> Use this tag for questions about the data management layer for machine learning on various platforms.

or maybe:

> Use this tag for questions about using the API of the data management layer for machine learning on various platforms.

None of the questions are closed so I'm not able to add guidance on when not to use the tag and as I'm not an SME I have to assume the questions in that tag are used in a programming context. If not, then either the wiki or excerpt needs to be extended to include which aspects of [feature-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-store) are valid in questions.

Comment: if you rather have this as community wiki so we can all improve on the suggestions made here, let me know. Otherwise I'll take the burden of the downvotes and you write your own competing answer.

Comment: the better is the first 'Use this tag for questions about the data management layer for machine learning on various platforms.', because feature-store concept covers not only API but persistent layer, UI, etc. (it is the reason, why I mentioned the term concept).

Comment: proposal 'Use this tag for questions about the data management layer for machine learning (feature-store concept) on various platforms.'

Comment: The tag feature-store is similar such as tag mlops, it can cover all (API, configuration, persistent layer, etc.).  What about to mention 'Use this tag for questions about the data management layer for machine learning (feature-store concept covers API, persistent layer, UI, etc.) on various platforms.' But this description is little hard for reading. BTW: in many of cases feature store does not use pure DB layer but also key-value storage and from these reasons it is better to use term 'persistent layer'

Answer (score 6):

Your wiki proposal seems jargon heavy to me.

- **feature** -- Machine learning term for "piece of data"
- **store** -- Term for a database

So, more simply, a feature store is a database for pieces of data used in machine learning.

ML models typically expect to find all the data they need to use in a single place and want to look up their data by key.  To run quickly, ML models typically need low latency access to data, so data access needs to be performant.  As such, a feature store is usually implemented as a key/value database.  It will come with an API that allows models to find and fetch data. It will typically support ETLs for loading data into it.  It will often have analytics that show which models fetch which data and in what amounts. It may offer a UI to navigate and control all this.

Comment: I vote for, store -- Term for a database or NoSQL solution such as (key-value storage, graph storage, etc.). Second point is that FeatureStore support as you mention quick access to the data (via key-value in memory solution e.g. REDIS, ...) but also access to long data for model experiment, discovery where data is stored to slower storage such as parquet files, ... . Easy to say feature-store has metalayer and two storages, one for faster-realtime execution (via key-value in memory storage) and one for longer data typically for model building.

Comment: Can you add to the wiki term 'ACID' also? See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-hudi/info